# JAVAFX: GUI element alignment and grouping problem

Tags: javafx

TASK :Write a JavaFX GUI application that allows the user to pick a set of pizza toppings using a set of check boxes. Assuming each topping cost 50 cents, and a plain pizza costs $10, display the cost of the pizza. Note that, once a topping is checked or unchecked, the cost of pizza should update automatically.

Your application should closely resemble the following output format, although the choice of toppings could be different:

**REQUEST :  an efficient way to align all element as shown in pic "expectation"
I am not sure how to group Pizza cost and toppings into one set of group to display as a pane efficiently.**

[image: my solution]

[image: expectation]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javafx.scene.Group;



public class DisplayPizzaCost extends Application{    
        private static final double  TOPPING_COST = 0.5d;
        private static final NumberFormat COST_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        private static final String  PIZZA_COST = "Pizza Cost: ";

        private double  pizzaCost = 10.0d;
        private Label  totalPizzaCostLabel;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        CheckBox extraCheesCheckBox = getCheckBox("Extra Cheese");
        CheckBox greenPepperCheckBox = getCheckBox("Green Pepper");
        CheckBox PepperoniCheckBox = getCheckBox("Pepperoni");
        CheckBox OnionCheckBox = getCheckBox("Onion");
        CheckBox SausageCheckBox = getCheckBox("Sausage");
        CheckBox AnchoviesCheckBox = getCheckBox("Anchovies");

        totalPizzaCostLabel = new Label(PIZZA_COST + COST_FORMAT.format(pizzaCost));
        totalPizzaCostLabel.setFont(new Font(13.0d));
        
        VBox toppings1V = new VBox(extraCheesCheckBox, PepperoniCheckBox, SausageCheckBox);
        toppings1V.setSpacing(20);        
        VBox toppings2V = new VBox(greenPepperCheckBox, OnionCheckBox, AnchoviesCheckBox);
        toppings2V.setSpacing(20);

        HBox hBox = new HBox(toppings1V, toppings2V);
        hBox.setSpacing(30);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                
        VBox CostLabel = new VBox(totalPizzaCostLabel);
        CostLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        
        Group root = new Group(hBox,CostLabel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,170);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Pizza Cost");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    private CheckBox getCheckBox(String text) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(text);
        cb.setOnAction(this::processCheckBoxAction);
        return cb;
    }

    private void processCheckBoxAction(ActionEvent event) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) event.getSource();
        if (cb.isSelected()) {
            pizzaCost += TOPPING_COST;
        }
        else {
            pizzaCost -= TOPPING_COST;
        }
        totalPizzaCostLabel.setText(PIZZA_COST + COST_FORMAT.format(pizzaCost));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: as to the problem - work through a tutorial about layouts or re-read the relevant chapter of your coursebook, at the very least read the javadoc: there are several layout classes, each with a specific behaviour (hint: don't use Group - do some research to understand why not :)

Comment: Find a tutorial on `GridPane`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/form.htm

Comment: I used to do any static view in `SceneBuilder` first, and they translated that to code.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but I used `BorderPane` in this example. When I first started, I always created views in `SceneBuilder` first. After that, I would use the setting from `SceneBuilder` to build my GUI in code. Most of the time, if `Labels` or `TextFields` need to be aligned, `GridPane` is probably what you will need.

**`FXML` from `SceneBuilder`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="345.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <StackPane BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="50.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" vgap="10.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <CheckBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Extra Cheese">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="25.0" />
                     </font>
                  </CheckBox>
                  <CheckBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pepperoni" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="25.0" />
                     </font>
                  </CheckBox>
                  <CheckBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Sausage" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="25.0" />
                     </font>
                  </CheckBox>
                  <CheckBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Green Pepper" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="25.0" />
                     </font>
                  </CheckBox>
                  <CheckBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Onion" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="25.0" />
                     </font>
                  </CheckBox>
                  <CheckBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Anchovies" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="25.0" />
                     </font>
                  </CheckBox>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Pizza Cost: $10.00" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="39.0" />
         </font>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="40.0" />
         </padding>
      </Label>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

**Pure Code**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import static javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_PREF_SIZE;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class App extends Application
{
   

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        
        //Create center root nodes.        
        //Create left nodes.
        CheckBox cbExtraCheese = new CheckBox("Extra Cheese");
        cbExtraCheese.setFont(Font.font("System", 25));
        CheckBox cbPepperoni = new CheckBox("Pepperoni");
        cbPepperoni.setFont(Font.font("System", 25));
        CheckBox cbSausage = new CheckBox("Sausage");
        cbSausage.setFont(Font.font("System", 25));
        
        //Create right nodes.
        CheckBox cbGreenPeppers = new CheckBox("GreenPeppers");
        cbGreenPeppers.setFont(Font.font("System", 25));
        CheckBox cbOnions = new CheckBox("Onions");
        cbOnions.setFont(Font.font("System", 25));
        CheckBox cbAnchovies = new CheckBox("Anchovies");
        cbAnchovies.setFont(Font.font("System", 25));        
        
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setMaxSize(USE_PREF_SIZE, USE_PREF_SIZE);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setHgap(50);        
        gridPane.add(cbExtraCheese, 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(cbPepperoni, 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(cbSausage, 0, 2);        
        gridPane.add(cbGreenPeppers, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(cbOnions, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(cbAnchovies, 1, 2);
        
        StackPane centerRoot = new StackPane(gridPane);
        root.setCenter(centerRoot);
        
        //Create bottom root nodes.
        Label lblCost = new Label("Pizza Cost: $10.00");
        lblCost.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        lblCost.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        lblCost.setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.BOLD, 39));
        lblCost.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 40, 0));
        
        root.setBottom(lblCost);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 345);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Printing FX");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: relaxing to do homework, isn't it <g> Anyway: I know that you know the general don't-hard-code-sizing-constraints-never-ever, so wondering why you do in the fxml?

Comment: @kleopatra, I make an exception if the node is the root node that sets the scene.  Do you see any pitfalls in doing that?

Comment: never-ever is never-ever :) why would you make an exception for the root (btw: you also seem hard-code the row constraints)? It's also a layout that adjusts to window size, hard-coding anything will prevent that.

Comment: I didn't notice the row constraints. That must be the default in SceneBuilder when you add the node. As for the root node, it's similar to setting the scene size. When I set the root node size, I don't set the scene size.

Comment: beware: nitpicking :) _it's similar to setting the scene size_ similar, but not the same. Actually, the difference is the invers of what I would have expected, given dynamic changes to the root which affects its size: my expectation was that setting the pref on the root would prevent updating its/scene/window size while setting the initial size of the scene would allow it. In fact, it's just the other way round - my learn item of Easter Monday, thanks :)